# Can a Java JAX-RS request method be called with a runtime resolved GenericType argument?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I would like to take the code

```
WebTarget targetBase = ...
targetBase.path("some_path").request(MEDIA_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<MyModel>>(){});
```

and write something like this

```
public <T> T getViaRest( GenericType<T> myGenericType ) {
  return targetBase.path("some_path").request(MEDIA_TYPE).get(myGenericType);
}
...
getViaRest(new GenericType<List<MyModel>>(){});
getViaRest(new GenericType<List<MyModel2>>(){});
...
```

This way I can have a general getViaRest method that I put my custom logging and error handling code in, and it can be used for all my models.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add logging for the client, you should probably do it with a client request [filter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html). You can register the filter in the client via a [Feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html).

Example:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(NEW_FEATURE);

WebTarget targetBase = client.target("api");

targetBase.path("some_path").request(MEDIA_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<MyModel>>(){});
```

the Feature (you can extract it in a class of its own):

```
private static final Feature NEW_FEATURE = new Feature() {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new ClientRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
};
```

You can also add different features, depending of what you're trying to do.